# Can sqlite3_exec execute several pragmas in one call?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to execute several PRAGMA calls in the same sqlite3_exec statement?

Answer (score 0):

It does't support. However you can use sqlite3 (CLI) to perform several PRAGMA using "-init" option.